# Android ViewPager depth effect

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe, gesture

I have a "flat" ViewPager on my app. I saw DeviantArt's pager and its cool transition between fragments in pager when using lateral swipe. How i can achieve this effect? This is done with a library?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should do some research of your own into how this might be done. The Android docs would be a good start and then if you are still having problems, provided details of what *you* have done. Please don't expect others to do research for you.

Comment: Kerry, i used ViewPager long time ago, I checked Android documentation, but had no idea about that parameter. today, i looked a bit in the API, but didn't found anything. My fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a custom page transformation is a built-in feature of the ViewPager. You need to tell the ViewPager (using `setPageTransformer`) to use a custom transformation - the example ZoomOutPageTransformer described in the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer) looks like it would suit your needs.